# Read data inside iFrame from parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Is their any way / hack to get data values from iFrame content from parent script.

I know reading values from Cross Origin iFrames is not allowed in Web Browsers due to security concerns.

Is their any hack or method to read that value.

I tired.

```
$("body").text();
```

But, this returns the iFrame embbed code instead of the content inside the iFrame.

As, the code is inside the browser, their may be some hack to read that values. 
I need to read a span from the webpage loaded inside iFrame.

Comment: What kind of a security feature it would be, if there was a hack?

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are looking for but sounds like it could work https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/

Comment: @Teemu Agree ..  But, here i need help to find some way to read values. Its not like i'm hacking or breaking anything. Just reading values of webpage loaded from iFrame.

Comment: The only way is to use proxy script that will fetch the page and return it you. so you can use in Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that.

If such a thing existed, it would be a major security vulnerability, and would be promptly fixed by browser developers.

Comment: Can we read iframe content through chrome extensions installed by user ?  Or listen the url requests and intercept the response ? I'm not sure just figuring out any possibility